# field _type in library shanty mongodb

Tags: php, zend-framework, mongodb

Could you please explain me about _type field that appears in my document?
When I save document using Shanty MongoDb, _type field is saved although I don't save it myself.

```
$subscriber = new MyDocument($formData);                    
$subscriber->save();
```

MyDocument is inhereted from Shanty_Mongo_Document. Can I deleted field _type field without problems? 
I use this one to prevent inserting the field:

```
protected function preInsert()
{
    unset($this->_data['_type']);       
}
```

What is this field for? Can I delete it easily?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better way but I this in my document class to prevent storing _type field:

```
protected function preInsert()
{
    unset($this->_data['_type']);       
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It appears that Shanty does this so that you can query for document classes and sub-classes. It mentions it in the section "Querying for subclasses is easy" at https://github.com/coen-hyde/Shanty-Mongo#readme.

Comment: Can you please, tell if I can delete it as I do it? What's the consquences of it?